# When does Crashlytics send the log on iOS?

Tags: ios, crashlytics

Immediately after the crash or at restart only? I'm asking it because if the user uninstalls the app due to a crash, it will never turn out then in case, Crashlytics sends the log just after the running the app again.

Comment: For the reasons, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26798345/why-is-restart-needed-to-send-crash-log-on-ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vignesh is correct. If you want any source confirming it , i found this from [Crashlytics site](http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/92523-why-can-t-i-have-xcode-connected-)

Following are steps mentioned there to get a test crash report.

- Launch simulator
- Press stop
- Launch your app and force a crash
- Relaunch the app from simulator
- See the crash report in the web dashboard

Here 4th step confirms that it sends report only on next launch.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

If your app is crashed nothing can run from your crashed app . Hence it has to send on restart only.

Comment: But the exception is caught. During this?